# Can't read the value of a CheckBox

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a weird problem.
I have a form that looks like the one in the image
[image]

Those checkboxes are generated with a peace of code like this one (there is a loop that increments the i and the l ...everything is fine there because the other components are generated through the same piece of code and I have no problem getting their values):

```
Public Sub AddCboxs(form, masina, nrmasini, replicare, nrcboxs)
Dim i, k, l As Integer
i = 0
l = 1
Do While i < nrmasini
        Do While l < nrcboxs + 1
Set cControl = form.Controls("iooly" & i).Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "sc" & l & "oly" & i, True)
            With cControl
                .Width = 15
                .Height = 16
                .Top = 200 + k
                .Left = 205

            End With
        k = k + 35
        l = l + 1
    Loop
l = 1
k = 0
i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Now... I want to do the following thing. If the SC checkbox is checked I want to do some stuff that you'll see in the following piece of code ... without checking the value of the checkbox the code works just fine and does what I want it to do... but the problem is that I need to do it just when the checkbox is checked.

```
Public Sub CalcOly()
Dim i, j, k As Integer
Dim Rand, ContorVal, ContorTotal As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Config")
Dim cControl As Control
i = 0
j = 1
ContorVal = 0
Do While i < 5
    Do While j < 3
    Rand = 30
    If raport.Controls("sc" & j & "oly" & i).Value = True Then
            Do While ws.Cells(Rand, 1).Value <> "" And Rand < 65536
                If ws.Cells(Rand, 1).Value = raport.Controls("combo" & j & "oly" & i).Value Then
                    Set cControl = raport.Controls("iooly" & i).Add("Forms.Label.1", "valoare" & j & "oly" & i, True)
                    With cControl
                        .Caption = Int(ws.Cells(Rand, 2).Value * raport.Controls("q" & j & "oly" & i).Value) & " RON"
                        .Width = 55
                        .Height = 14
                        .Top = 42 + k
                        .Left = 225
                    End With
                    ContorVal = ContorVal + Int(ws.Cells(Rand, 2).Value * raport.Controls("q" & j & "oly" & i).Value)
                End If
            Rand = Rand + 1
            Loop
    End If
    j = j + 1
    k = k + 35
    Loop
Set cControl = raport.Controls("iooly" & i).Add("Forms.Label.1", "totalval" & "oly" & i, True)
                    With cControl
                        .Caption = ContorVal & " RON"
                        .Width = 55
                        .Height = 14
                        .Top = 350
                        .Left = 225
                    End With
k = 0
j = 1
i = i + 1
ContorVal = 0
Loop
End Sub
```

Now here's the weird thing... if I click on CALCUL VALOARE (which calls the CalcOly procedure) it executes the code but no matter if the SC checkbox is checked or no it shows no value. If I go on page Olympia 4 or Olympia 5 it does what it needs to do but again... ignoring if the SC checkboxes are checked or not.
I tried to get the value of the checkbox in a separate caption and I observed that it doesn't get it... I really don't know why!
Thanks a lot for your help!

Later: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPb617JxgtI I've uploaded a video to see how strange the app acts. I don't get it... if I remove the If that checks if the checkbox is True or False it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You should show us the piece of code that generates the first checkboxes, especially if your other checkboxes work properly.

That said, several things:

**In VBA, you can't declare variables this way:**

```
Dim i, j, k As Integer
Dim Rand, ContorVal, ContorTotal As Long
```

You have to do:

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
Dim Rand As Long, ContorVal As Long, ContorTotal As Long
```

See [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DeclaringVariables.aspx)

**Debug**

What did you see when debuging your userform. Do the `raport.Controls("sc" & j & "oly" & i)` exist ?
By the same way, you should have a look at `raport.Controls()` collection to see what are the elements and their properties.
That would tell you if your Controls were really created the way you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I didn't knew I couldn't declare the variables that way... I always did it like that... Yes the objects exists because I made a loop that printed their name in a caption  and everything was fine. The debuger doesn't show any errors...

Comment: I added the other parts of the procedure that generates the checkboxes

Comment: The debuger might not show any error but your code doesn't work as expected. You'd better set a breakpoint on the `If raport.Controls("sc" & j & "oly" & i).Value = True Then` line and set a spy or Watch value... also. See [here](http://krgreenlee.blogspot.com/2006/04/programming-excel-vba-debugging-for.html) or [here](http://www.eng.auburn.edu/~tplacek/courses/3600/notes8c.pdf)

Comment: Here's what I did... I put a label in wich at the begining I tried this: `raport.Label1.Caption = raport.Label1.Caption + raport.Controls("sc" & j & "oly" & i).Name` ... it worked fine... all the names were there... then I tried this: `raport.Label1.Caption = raport.Label1.Caption + Str(raport.Controls("sc" & j & "oly" & i).Value)` ...it worked fine but here's the problem... if I changed the values in any of the first three pages the changes didn't took place... if I changed them on page 4 or page 5 it worked...

Comment: so for some strange reasons it doesn't get the values of the checkboxes from the first 3 pages and I really don't know why since the checkboxes exists and are read by the loop...

Comment: Just to be clear, you are able to declare variables that way, however in this case, i, j, Rand and ContorVal will all be Variants, not Ints or Longs.  I don't think that it's causing your problem.

Comment: From the code I can see, it looks like "q" isn't initialized.  Could that be causing a problem?

Comment: It's initialized but I didn't put it here... I added just the part of the code with the checkbox... there's something similar in that procedure for the "q" textbox, or the "sn" textbox or the comboboxes ...but if I add them all here there would be too much code that doesn't have much to do with the problem (I hope).

Comment: Please join this chat room to avoid extended discussion in comments: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2755/excel-cant-read-the-value-of-a-checkbox

Answer (score 0):

This seems a bit obscure but from the help for the `Add` method of the `Controls` property:

> If you add a control at run time, you must use the exclamation syntax
>   to reference properties of that control. For example, to return the
>   Text property of a control added at run time, use the following
>   syntax:
>
> userform1!thebox.text

You could try changing:

`If raport.Controls("sc" & j & "oly" & i).Value = True Then`

to:

`If raport!("sc" & j & "oly" & i).Value = True Then`

edit: I'd originally used a separate variable to build up the string but that wouldn't work as the program would look for a control with the same name as the variable rather than the value of the variable

edit2: if that doesn't work you could try:

`If raport!"sc" & j & "oly" & i.Value = True Then`

but it would depend on the precedence of `!` and `.` relative to `&`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It doesn't work with "!"... it gives me an error: Type declaraction charracter doesn't match declared data type

Answer (score 0):

Just use these for your button click

```
if checkboxname.value = true then 
  invoke your function 
end if
```